# how to get data from td in watir which looks like " status"

Tags: ruby, watir

```
<td align="Left">

<font color="navy">

<b>Status &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     &nbsp;&nbsp; : </b>

</font>

<font color="red"><b>Registered</b>
</font>

</td>
```

i want to do this

```
if(cell.text==like(status))
  puts "yes"
end
```

actually in my table there are random tr and td , so i want to fetch the text of td which have status text in it. because it is fixed and "Registered" text may be change.
so on the basis of %status% i want to select the td.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can locate element by regular expression:

```
browser.td(:text => /^Status/)
```

Comment: it is not working.
 row.cells.each do |cell|
    cell.text
 row_array << cell.text
  if(cell.text == /^Status/)
           
puts  "/Rate/"
end           end

Comment: i do if(cell.text  =~ /Status(.*)/ )
             #browser.td(:text => /^Status/)
            puts  "/Rate/"
          
                  end